# How to report WebService statistics in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, analysis

I have nearly 8 methods in my .asmx. This .asmx helps client side to get data from the database. Client sides are Blackberry and iPhone. 
I need to report how many times do these reports called from the client side.

So I need a way to make e report.aspx maybe, that shows statistics about the methods usage and thereby the client application usage.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to store it somewhere on the server. 
you can easily just get this report from web server log, since it stores URL and GET string (check your IIS logging config to see if you record GET information)